# Trying to implement telegrambots-spring-boot-starter and create Telegram bot, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram-bot

I use Spring boot and telegrambots-spring-boot-starter dependency. I did all things as it showed in this repository:
https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/tree/master/telegrambots-spring-boot-starter.
But it didn't work.

**My pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>secretary.bot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>secretary.bot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My Bot class:**

```
package com.telegram.secretary.bot;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;


import java.util.List;

@Component
public class MySecretaryBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "Oyaqbot";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "5240178378:AAHA6GVOT2fGp_pFMyXD75LEBlms6iEVtSs";
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegister() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        String command = update.getMessage().getText();

        if(command.equals("/hello")){
            String message = "Hello, dear friend!";

            SendMessage response = new SendMessage();
            response.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
            response.setText(message);

            try {
                execute(response);
            }
            catch (TelegramApiException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdatesReceived(List<Update> updates) {

    }
}
```

**My Main Spring boot class:**

```
package com.telegram.secretary.bot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Note: According to the repository telegram bot starter for Spring boot automatically registers your bot and no need registration code. And ApiContextInitializer.init(); method also doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: If you look at the code for the bot it uses Spring Boot 2.5 and not Spring Boot 2.6. Now it doesn't have the mean it doesn't work with 2.6 but it definitely hasn't been tested with it. So I would suggest downgrading to 2.5.x (whatever the latest version of that is).

Answer (score 3):

Your version of `telegrambots-spring-boot-starter` probably was not updated for Spring Boot 2.7.0 and newer support.
Since Spring Boot 2.7.0 there was a change related to auto-configuration ([Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#changes-to-auto-configuration)).

In order to make it work – create a new file under `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` and put the next line there:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.starter.TelegramBotStarterConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set scanning directive.
Try this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.telegram.secretary.bot",
        "org.telegram.telegrambots"
})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! With Spring Boot 3 the following in the component scan `org.telegram.telegrambots` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your bot manually.

1. Create bean for TelegramBotsAPI:

   ```
    @Bean  
    public TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi() {  
        return new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);  
    }
   ```
2. Register your bot in the constructor:

   ```
    @Component
    public class MySecretaryBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

        @Autowired
        public MySecretaryBot(TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi) {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this);
        }

        ...

    }
   ```